# Change NSAtributedString Color and Font for Empty Range TextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I recently started investigating how NSAtributedString works. I am building something similar to rich text editor using NSAtributedString. I have a custom written CustomRichTextEditor:UITextView and I want to overwrite default attributes for NSAtributedString using this code below:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName,[UIColor darkGrayColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil];
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [self.richTextEditor.attributedText mutableCopy];
[attrStr setAttributes:attributes
                 range:NSMakeRange(0, self.richTextEditor.attributedText.string.length-1)

 ];
self.richTextEditor.attributedText = attrStr;
```

However, because my editor is empty and range is unknown, I crash with error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds'**

How can I set the font and color for NSAtributedString correctly when the range is unknown?

Comment: Why not self.richTextEditor.attributedText.string.length? You're cutting the last character.

Comment: The problem is obvious but how can I fix it with no range?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you set the ranges length like this:

```
self.richTextEditor.attributedText.string.length-1
```

which can make errors. If you make 0 - 1 to an unsigned integer it will suddenly becomes pretty big and therefore your range will be super huge.

So what you need to do is check if you have a `string.length > 0` before you make your range.
Executing all the code is anyway useless if your string is empty...

Comment: Range [0,0] works without errors but produces no results. How would I set color and font then?

Comment: Range [0,0] works of course but would have no effect. But if you have no text anyway, why would you want to change it's font?
The out of bounds exception that you had was caused be Range [0, 0-1] because that is like Range [0, MAX_INT].

Comment: I want to change the default settings of font and color. That's all.